# How Does Bender Store Everything?

Tags: futurama, bender-rodriguez

Bender Rodriguez. The lovable robot with a SERIOUS alcohol problem.

One thing always perplexed me, though. How does he store everything?

[image]

How did he get all these treasures? He stored them in his abdomen for years on end. But many of these riches are far larger than his midsection (see the bender to the right, one row back, and the bender one back and one toward the center of the pirate).

And we see him do this with his majestic midriff multiple times throughout the series.

But how is this terrific thorax possible? In- and Out-Of-World explanations welcome.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Hammerspace

Comment: @calccrypto That's very interesting and a good point, but I was looking for something more Futurama specific. But it could be a good answer.

Comment: In the case you've highlighted, he didn't store any of these artworks in his compartment. He just held them in his arms. These are time travel duplicates that were waiting in the limestone caves.

Comment: @Valorum That's very true, but the picture was only intended to jog one's memory. It was the only one I could find of Bender with a reality breaking amount of treasure, however I am at this moment looking for a better picture of him actually putting it in him. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: He doesn't have an alcohol problem. Robots in the Futurama world use alcohol for fuel.

Comment: @Verdan https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18334/68872